# How to debug a page not fully rendered in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I was asked to look into a portal to fix an issue with forum and run update scripts. I agreed, having experience with DNN and Drupal. I have done it - no issues there. I thought.

I was told that the footer disappeared, and a user was right. When I run a page - it ends abruptly. No `</body>` tag, no end of page scripts; but also no error messages.

Question is - how do I debug it? Is there a log in wp-admin? or debug toolbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if your footer.php has the function call `wp_footer();` at the end of the file, right before `</body>`.

To debug in WordPress, you will have to edit your wp-config.php file.

In wp-config.php look for the line `define('WP_DEBUG', false);` and set this to true e.g., `define('WP_DEBUG', true); // or false = on or off`.

Now add the following lines underneath the line we just edited.

`if(WP_DEBUG){

  define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);

  define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false); // true to display on site false to hide but still writes to debug.log

  @ini_set('display_errors', 0); // wp-content/debug.log

}`

So the complete code should look like the following:


`define('WP_DEBUG', true); // or false`

if(WP_DEBUG){
  define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
  define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false); // true to display on site false to hide but still writes to debug.log
  @ini_set('display_errors', 0); // wp-content/debug.log
}

What this will do is turn on debugging in WordPress, it will not show errors on screen but it will write them to a file named *debug.log* located in */wp-content/debug.log* where you can go back and open it up to debug your problems.

Good luck.

Comment: Brilliant - so there is a way to have debug info, but not showing it to a user. (I don't have a test/dev env). thanks!