# Wordpress - Page not fully rendering HTML

Tags: html, wordpress

I have a Wordpress based website in development stages and it has been fully operational for a long time. This morning when I went on to check a few pages and to make a few changes.

When I go to one page to work on it this is what I [see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ananR.png). The page has fully loaded before and is laid out in rows of 3. Usually there is an image below this page and there is around 50 sub sections to choose from. It seems the HTML just doesn't fully render.

This is what the source looks like;

```
 <div style='clear: both;'></div></div></div><div class="w3eden  " id="row_52ca839dc0e5c" style="" ><div class="row-fluid minimax_content_area"> 
    <div class="span4 minimax_column" id="column_1_52ca839dc0e5c">
     <div class='minimax_module MiniMax_RichText'><p style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: large;">Agilent 3479XA</span></p>        
    </div><div class='minimax_module minimax_image'>
```

And that's where is cuts off. I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20350752/how-to-debug-a-page-not-fully-rendered-in-wordpress) post but to no avail.

Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Guys, I just found out the answer. I created a custom style for one of the plugins and one of my colleagues updated Wordpress without asking me. The Minimax image was still referencing the custom style but because WP udpated it removed the code.

Thanks for all the suggestions.

Comment: From the screenshot, it seems to render just the same content as the source you posted. I'm guessing, what you are expecting may be rendered via some javascript function that runs on page load. Do you at least have firebug installed on your browser? It helps you to see whether a css fails to load or a script error occurs.

Comment: There are no errors that I can see via Firebug or Chrome dev tools. I just also noticed that on the page that errors the Wordpress admin bar doesn't show at the top. Does that help any?

Comment: Are there any specific plugins that you may have enabled and is running on the specific page? you might want to disable each plugin for a while.

Comment: I just went through and disabled each plugin to test it and nothing worked. It's weird because each plugin is globally active, i.e. breadcrumb plugin, and everything was working fine yesterday. As far as I can tell it's the only page that doesn't load fully. The worst thing is that it's one of the larger pages that took time to make.

Comment: This could be deduced to server side error then as what Steven Don answered below. You might want to check the error logs. However, may I at least know how's that image that should appear below being rendered? it seems to halt at this div tag: <div class='minimax_module minimax_image'>, does the image have a high resolution?

Comment: I just worked out the problem, thanks for your help. Edited original question.

Comment: That's cool. You might want to answer your own question instead and revert to the original question you posted. Your'e welcome!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a client issue. Something is causing the output to stop. This could be caused by an error in WordPress, a missing function, a corrupt source file, an extension... anything, really. On a development system, PHP error output would tell you what's wrong. On a production system, this is usually disabled, but the errors are commonly stored in the site's error_log. Check that to see what error is being thrown.